# How to call an Action method using ajax for a button click which is in partial view in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC. I got a situation where I need to pass a parameter from view to controller on the button click (the button is in partial view), which then renders another partial view in the same page.

Steps followed:

1. I used jquery button click event for the button of partial view.
2. I made an ajax call to pass the parameters from my view to the controller.

The following is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btninPartialView", function(e){
    var data = $("txtinPartialView").val();
    $("#mainPageContainer").load("/Controller/Action", data, function(){
        $.ajax({
            //url: @Url.Action("Action", "Controller"),
            type: GET,
            data: {
                id: data
            },
            success: function(){
            }
            error: function(){
            }
        })
    }    
})
```

Problem:
The problem is that, the data I'm received in the action method is `null`.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide please your controller's method code

Comment: Can you please check with chrome developer tools console tab after clicking of button, check if any errors if not check network tab if the ajax call is successful or not.. If it is not successful, give me the error ..

Comment: why are you using both load and ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#btninPartialView", function(e){
var data = $("txtinPartialView").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    type: GET,
    data: {
        id: data
    },
    success: function(result){
$("#mainPageContainer").html(result);
    }
    error: function(){

})
})
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with the arguments your Action method is accepting.

for example if signature is

```
public ActionResult Action1(string name)
```

then you need to pass the data as

```
var data = { name :  $("txtinPartialView").val() }
```

Comment: Yes, it is the same signature. The signature I used is as follows: public ActionResult Action (string id){}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing both jquery ajax and load function, load function sends an ajax call behind the scenes, so you need to use one of them, not both, so try like:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btninPartialView", function(e){

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            type: GET,
            data: {
                id: $("txtinPartialView").val()
            },
            success: function(response){
                $("#mainPageContainer").html(response);
            },
            error: function(){
            }
        });
 });
```

Comment: When I used @Url.Action, it isn't working for me, but url: "/controller/action" worked perfectly. Thank you guys..